# agilent 34903 Actuator/Relay card not working in remote mode

Tags: switches, relay

I have a simple SPDT relay on the 34903A card, hooked into a 34972A DAQ Unit.

The COM is a 5V supply from an external source,and I have the NO pin hooked up to an input externally as well.

When testing this relay on the front, it works fine.

However, I am unable to actuate it remotely. I send the following cmd:

```
"ROUT:CLOS (@301)"
```

I dont get any errors back and I get a return message from the cmd. However, the relay doesnt actually switch.

If I use the same command on an unused channel(@302), it works even remotely.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use a card in switch mode and scan mode at the same time.

Comment: sorry, can you elaborate? How do I make the card either mode?